# Выбор базы на основе пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Хотелось бы услышать Ваши идеи касательно задумки:
Отдельная база для каждого города. Вот допустим приходит юзверь на сайт, перед ним окно выбора города, он выбирает город и должна показываться инфа из базы для определенного города.
Была мысль реализовать все через

```
mysql connect
```

но я работаю в Simpla CMS и там конфиг подключения к базе. Каким образом мне можно менять конфиги местами в зависимости от выбора пользователя?

Comment: То есть у Вас базы заточены под города? Для каждого города своя БД?

Comment: Да, для каждого города своя бд, их пару штук.

Comment: Вы настаиваете на этом? Или смена логика Вашего приложения приветствуется?

Comment: Я готов выслушать Ваши предложения

Comment: Пожалуйста распишите все подробно в вопросе и я отвечу на него. Например: Какие таблицы примерно есть, какого рода инфа и все остальное.

Comment: Сотпровождать сложно будет. А если город надо добавить, создавать новую БД, править конфиги, еще что нибудь. потом в БД наверняка будет одинаковая инфа для всех городов, справочники какие нибудь. Не проще ли держать одну БД и в нужных таблицах добавить колонку "город"

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade это интернет-магазин со всеми вытекающими

Comment: Согласен с @Mike, нет смысла делать несколько баз с отдельными городами. Если вы разделяете города с целью партицирования, то проще будет обойтись несколькими отдельными таблицами (одна или несколько таблиц на город), чем отдельными базами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это плохая идея. Вам придется либо для каждого города держать отдельный набор пользователей, либо намертво привязывать пользователя к городу. Иначе вы не сможете связать пользователя с его данными, расположенными на другом сервере. В результате чего простая операция смена жительства будет превращаться в адскую задачу миграции у вас в backend-части сайта. В адскую же задачу превращается сбор статистики по всем городам (а если это интернет-магазин, как вы пишите в комментариях, то вам статистика потребуется). Кроме того, часть схемы и данных для каждого города у вас будет дублироваться и ее придется как-то синхронизировать при обновлении.

Если вы хотите добиться этим масштабирования, у вас будет крайне неравномерная нагрузка - сверхнагруженные базы данных Москвы и Питера, и простаивающие остальные.

Чтение лучше масштабировать репликацией, запись репликацией не масштабируется, но ее можно дробить Web-сервисами. Скажем, каталог товаров в одной базе данных и одном приложении, а комментарии и голосования реализованы в виде Web-сервиса, который взаимодействует с сайтом исключительно через JS. Счетчики просмотров стали создавать ощутимую нагрузку - выносите в отдельный Web-сервис.